# I have a problem in getting list of students whose result is not in the result table for (current term, current class and current year)

Tags: mysql

I am working on a school project. I am storing the result of students using PHP in the MYSQL database. here I have a problem I want a list of students whose result is not added yet for Ongoing Term(i.e 1.First Term), onGoing Session(i.e 1.2020-2021), and the current class(3.Third Class) of the student.
Because the Previous Result of that student is in the same table.

*Table1 : result(result_id, student_id, term_id, session_id, course_id, marks)*

*Table2 : student(std_id, std_name, class_id)*

```
 SELECT DISTINCT s.std_id, s.std_name, 
 FROM student s
 LEFT OUTER JOIN result r 
 ON s.std_id = r.std_id
 WHERE (((r.session_id is NULL && r.term_id is NULL) || (s.class_id != r.class_id)) || (r.term_id != 1)) 
 && (s.class_id=3));
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the exact table structure, sample input data, and the expected result matching to that input data

Comment: There's no `class_id` in the `result` table, you can't use `r.class_id`.

Answer (score 1):

All relationships between the two tables should be in the `ON` clause.

When doing a `LEFT JOIN` you should put the restrictions on the child table in the `ON` clause, not `WHERE`.

To check for a missing match, just test the primary key of the child table for `NULL`.

```
SELECT s.std_id, s.std_name
FROM student AS s
LEFT JOIN result AS r
ON s.std_id = r.std_id AND s.class_id = r.class_id AND r.term_id = 1
WHERE s.class_id = 3
AND r.result_id IS NULL
```